# Java Regex from beginning to first char

Tags: java, regex

How can I find any word from beginning of string to first char "~" using java?

Example:

Worddjjfdskfjsdkfjdsj ~ Word ~ Word

I want it to capture

Worddjjfdskfjsdkfjdsj

Comment: what is the difference between beginning and first char ?

Comment: edited it. now you can understand

Comment: Why a regex? A simple `indexOf()` will give the index of the first '~', then it's only a matter of grabbing the substring. Also, what should happen if there is no ~ at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it without regex in a very simple way.
First of all use indexOf() String method to find the index of the "~" character. Then use the substring() method to extract the string you are lookin for.
Here is an example:

```
String stringToProcess = "hello~world";
int charIndex = stringToProcess.indexOf('~');
String finalString = stringToProcess.substring(0, charIndex);
```

Comment: Just use `indexOf('~')` instead of `indexOf("~")` ;) Also, remind that there may be no '~' at all

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to capture all character from start of string `^` to first occurrence of `~`:

```
^[^~]*
```

`[^~]*` is negation based regex that matches 0 or more of anything but `~`

Answer (score 0):

Without regex it can be solved

Simply  split your string by `~`.

```
String str[] = "Worddjjfdskfjsdkfjdsj ~ Word ~ Word".split("~");
        System.out.println(str[0]);
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter here, however why splitting? Just use indexOf()

Comment: @fge I know.. Sample string given by User is having multiple `~`. That's why I thought `splitting`  is better.

Comment: @AJ. indexOf(int ch)

returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character.  Splitting is not good here.

Comment: Gys.. I know about `indexOf()`. I said splitting because, there might be a condition where user needs other two words also.

Comment: @AJ. what OP said is "`Worddjjfdskfjsdkfjdsj ~ Word ~ Word

I want it to capture

Worddjjfdskfjsdkfjdsj`"

Answer (score 0):

Here is regular expression that you can use: `^(.*?)~`.

However in your simple case you do not need regular expressions at all. Use `indexOf()` and `substring()`:

```
int tilda = str.indexOf('~');
if (tilda >= 0) {
    word = str.substring(0, tilda);
}
```